# Possible failed dependency injection using require throws 'is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection

I've looked through a few questions related to this error, and most of them seem to be a misunderstanding of what the keyword `this` means. I don't think I'm having that problem here. Mine might be some sort of circular dependency problem that I cannot articulate well enough to figure it out on my own.

I've tried to distill my problem into three files presented below.

### something.js

```js
var A = require('../lib/a');

var Something = function (type) {
    this.type = type;
};

Something.prototype.setTemplate = function (template) {
    this.template = template;
};

Something.prototype.applyTemplate = function () {
    var templateResult = this.template.calculate();
};


var factory = {};

factory.createSomething = function(type) {
    return new Something(type);
};

factory.createA = function (input) {
    return A.Make(input);
};

module.exports = factory;
```

### a.js

```js
var S = require('../prof/something');
var _ = require('underscore');

var A = function (input) {
    this.input = input;
};

A.prototype.calculate = function () {
    var calculation = 0;
    var _s = S.createSomething('hello world');
    // do calculation using input
    return calculation;
};

var factory = {};

factory.Make = function (input) {
    var a = new A(input);
    return a;
};

module.exports = factory;
```

### a_test.js

```js
describe('Unit: A Test', function() {

    var S = require('../prof/something');

    it('test 1', function() {
        var a = S.createA({
            //input
        });

        var s = S.createSomething('type1');

        s.setTemplate(a);
        s.applyTemplate(); // error
    });
});
```

The error gets thrown from the top level in `a_test.js` on the line with the comment `//error`. At the lowest level, the 'is not a function ' error is thrown  in `a.js` at the `S.createSomething(type)` method. It says that `S.createSomething()` is not a function.

I've put a breakpoint in at that line and tried to call functions from the underscore library, but it gives the same error. So it seems that the require statements inside `a.js` are not throwing errors, but none of the injected objects can be used to call functions from. The `a_test.js` file is being run with the karma library.

Am I violating some javascript paradigm by referencing back and forth between A and S? How can I do this properly?

---

Edit: I've done some further testing. It doesn't actually matter if the test file looks like this:

```js
describe('Unit: A Test', function() {

    var S = require('../prof/something');

    it('test 1', function() {
        var a = S.createA({
            //input
        });
        a.calculate(); // error
    });
});
```

An error is still thrown at the line indicated above.

Comment: Shouldn't have taken me this long to realize I have cyclic dependencies. Seems like some rearchitecturing may need to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in the question reference each other. This is called cyclic dependencies. The solution is to move the `var S = require('../prof/something');` statement into the calculate function like so:

### a.js

```js
// move the line from here
var _ = require('underscore');

var A = function (input) {
    this.input = input;
};

A.prototype.calculate = function () {
    var S = require('../prof/something'); // to here
    var calculation = 0;
    var _s = S.createSomething('hello world');
    // do calculation using input
    return calculation;
};

var factory = {};

factory.Make = function (input) {
    var a = new A(input);
    return a;
};

module.exports = factory;
```